# Convert all commits in a git repository to branches named sequentially?

Tags: git, github, repository

I am trying to figure out a huge code base.

Usually I run

```
git log
```

Then  I create a branch for each commit and investigate each sequentially.
Is there a way to create a branch for each commit and name them sequentially like 01, 02 ...etc.

Comment: Why do you create these branches? You can investigate commits as easily.

Comment: @RomainValeri That's just my workflow. I usually number the branches sequentially and go over them one by one.. or I just recreate the app for each commit on github.. but the commits are not easy to remember and go back and forth ...atleast for me

Comment: How about doing something like, ```git checkout HEAD~10``` -> do work -> ```git checkout HEAD~9``` --> do work -> .... ?

Comment: I admit I don't understand your workflow either, but see my answer below for a bash script that does what you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bash script will do the trick, creating a branch called B*n* starting at B1 for each commit. I assume you don't want to do your whole repo but some A..B range (excluding A, including B), which I'm arbitrarily setting at HEAD~10..HEAD here.

```
A=HEAD~10
B=HEAD
counter=0
for commit in `git rev-list --reverse $A..$B`; do
   counter=$((counter + 1))
   git branch B$counter $commit
done
```

Notice the use of `--reverse`: without it, this loop would assign branch B1 to the most recent commit; with it, the loop assigns B1 to the oldest commit.

Now, if you want to tag all the commits in the current branch, replace the `for` line with:

```
for commit in `git rev-list --reverse`; do
```

and if you want to tag all the commits in the repo, in every branch, use this `for` line:

```
for commit in `git rev-list --reverse --all`; do
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for...what if I want to do for the whole repo...??

Comment: Remove `$A..$B` and optionally add `--all` to the `rev-list` command line. See edited answer.